# Swagger URL to be accessed with authentication using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

Currently, I've added the configuration in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as below.

```
.antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
```

Now I want to add one AUTH api which will show first on swagger-ui and on success of that other APIs will be shown.

I have grouped API using versions v1 and v2 and all. I want all of these groups to be shown on the success of AUTH api.

Any advice will be appreciated.